# sealed class extends other sealed class

Tags: kotlin, extends, sealed-class

I am making various state models and side effect classes while using the MVI pattern. The state model can reduce the boilerplate by extending the interface that collects common parts, but the side effect class does not support extends as it is a sealed class. So I see the Toast side effect as boilerplate code. How can I get rid of this Toast side effect boilerplate code? Is there any way for the sealed class to extend to other sealed classes?

My state classes:

```kotlin
interface BaseMviState {
    val loaded: Boolean
    val exception: Exception?

    fun isException() = exception != null
}

data class MviJoinState(
    override val loaded: Boolean = false,
    override val exception: Exception? = null,
    val loginResult: Boolean = false,
    val registerResult: Boolean = false,
) : BaseMviState

data class MviRoomCreateState(
    override val loaded: Boolean = false,
    override val exception: Exception? = null,
) : BaseMviState
```

My side effect classes:

```kotlin
sealed class MviJoinSideEffect {
    data class SetupAutoLogin(val user: User) : MviJoinSideEffect()
    data class Toast(val message: String) : MviJoinSideEffect() // boilerplate
}

sealed class MviRoomCreateSideEffect {
    data class Toast(val message: String) : MviRoomCreateSideEffect() // boilerplate
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by extending the interface in a sealed class like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface BaseEvent {
    data class Toast(val toastMessage: String) : BaseEvent
}

sealed class Event : BaseEvent {
    data class Snackbar(val snackbarMessage: String) : Event()
}

fun main() {
    val event: BaseEvent = Event.Snackbar("Hi")

    when (event) {
        is BaseEvent.Toast -> todo(event.toastMessage)
        is Event.Snackbar -> todo(event.snackbarMessage)
    }
}

fun todo(message: String) {}
```

Comment: How do you overcome this error? 
"Inheritance of sealed classes or interfaces from different module is prohibited"

Comment: @VansuitaJr. you need to keep your BaseEvent interface in the same folder(package) with the sealed classes.

Comment: Yeap, I know, It's a kotlin limitation right?

Comment: @VansuitaJr. Yes. That's the limitation and core concept of the "sealed" keyword.